# How to multiply the same listview with a button click

Tags: android, xml

So [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snJnu.png) is the screenshot of my ListItem.  I have a floatingActionButton on another XML layout.  I want to populate my layout with this same listItem each time the floatingActionButton is clicked, one after another.  I know that I have to use a for loop for this but I'm stuck about how to repeat (re-create?) the same listItem at each button click.  I don't see why ArrayAdapters would be appropriate.  On my main UI thread, so far I only have my widgets referenced.

This is my listItem XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/semesterListItem"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="6dp"
        >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Semester 1"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#3F51B5"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="DELETE"
            android:layout_weight="0.6"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        >

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just call don't clear the arraylist before refreshing the adapter and you'll get the same items appended to your listview.

Comment: How?  I've never seen that.

Comment: paste your adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I assume you've array of data that you want to load to your listView. and when you tap the button(or reach the end of listView) more data will be loaded with same or different data.

```
public class MyClass extends Activity{

private ListView _lv;
private Button _btn;

//otherviews and stuff

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  super.setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);

  _btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
  _lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView); //listView in your layout 

       /*
          _arrayAdapter to load the data into your listView,
          if you want to load data from a webservice you'll
          have to make a custom adapter and replace like this
          MyAdapter _myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, dataList);

       */

           ArrayAdapter<String> _arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             your_array_list ); 
           // replace your_array_list with your array of data

     _lv.setAdapter(_arrayAdapter); 

     //button to add more data to listview
     _btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //add another row to the list
          _arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
             this, 
             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
             your_array_list ); 
          /* if you've more than one array you can 
             load the next array of data by replacing 
             your_array_list with new array here.*/

         _arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
         // notify the adapter to update list with new data. 
         // otherwise the new data won't show up. 

         });   
   }
```

Comment: There is no data.  The screenshot above shows one listitem.  I want to add another list item just like it at each floatactionbutton click.